# sending variables to php via ajax and jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, variables, geolocation

i want to request the users geolocation via html5-geolocation and send it to the next page
I've been told that i've to use ajax/jquery, so this is my code:

```
<form action="response.php">
        <button onclick="getLocation()">Start</button>

<script>

function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);
    } else { 
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
}

function successFunction(position) {
   var lat = position.coords.latitude;
   var longi = position.coords.longitude;

    $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "response.php",
  data: { latitude: lat, longitude: longi }
  }).done(function( msg ) {
  alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
});
}
</script>
</form>
```

and now i want to "echo" the latitude and longitude on my response.php page
but i have no idea how to do :'(
I tried this:

```
$latitude = $_POST["latitude"]; 
echo $latitude;
```

but the page is blank

Comment: check first that you have any value in `var lat`  `var longi `

Comment: what error you get in console ?

Comment: change your  function name  `successFunction` to `success` ?

Comment: You have just declared your function. Are you calling it somewhere?

Comment: Okay i changed the function name to succes, but still no result

Comment: Inspect the button and check it on the console you will get the error...

Comment: No i'm new to javascript and all this :/ i have no clue, i'll try to fix the problem for myself but cant find any solutions

Comment: @Juloius did you get data in `lat, longi`  . check in console or alert

Comment: Console shows no errors :/

Comment: @Juloius  can you add error message here or in question ? copy it from console

Comment: There's no error in the console

Comment: How can i check if the variable is empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This:

**index.html**:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <form action="response.php" method="post">
      <input type="hidden" id="latitude" name="latitude" value="" />
      <input type="hidden" id="longitude" name="longitude" value="" />
      <input type="submit" value="Start" />
    </form>
</body>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function getLocation() {

         var options = {
            enableHighAccuracy: true,
            timeout: 5000,
            maximumAge: 0
         };

        function success(pos) {
           successFunction(pos);
        };

        function error(err) {
            console.warn('ERROR(' + err.code + '): ' + err.message);
        };

        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error,options);
        } else { 
            //x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
        }
    }

    function successFunction(position) {
       var lat = position.coords.latitude;
       var longi = position.coords.longitude;

        $('#latitude').val(lat);
        $('#longitude').val(longi);
    }
    getLocation();
</script>
</html>
```

**response.php**:

```
<?php
    $latitude = $_POST["latitude"]; 
    $longitude = $_POST["longitude"]; 
    echo "Latitude:".$latitude."</br>";
    echo "longitude:".$longitude;
?>
```

Just create **index.html** copy and paste this code and make sure that **response.php** like this.

```
/yourprojectdirectory/index.html
/yourprojectdirectory/response.php
```

Comment: There is still a blank page :/
Im feeling really stupid right now, sorry guys :'(

Comment: @Juloius  have you loaded jquery library  in page ?

Comment: Yeah ofc, i think otherwise there would be an error

Comment: So what issue you are facing now?? Check your console.

Comment: Issue: my response.php is just blank

Comment: Try passing as GET and make sure the request is actually made

Comment: I tried it aggain, dont know whats wrong with my server but the page is still blank Im so sorry :/

Comment: There just this message: Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.
But no error or smth

Comment: NIce, now the alert says "data saved:...." but it stays on index,php and dont load the response.php^^

Answer (score 0):

```
function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);
    } else { 
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
}

function successFunction(position) {
   var lat = position.coords.latitude;
   var longi = position.coords.longitude;

    $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "response.php",
  data:"data="+ '{ "latitude":"'+ lat+'", "longitude": "'+longi+'" }'
  }).done(function(msg) {
  alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
});
}
</script>




$location =json_decode( preg_replace('/\\\"/',"\"",$_POST['data'])); 
print_r($location);
 $lat=$location->latitude;
 echo $lan=$location->longitude;
```